# Latex tables variable scale scientific paper

Tags: tables, pdftex

I am in the process of writing a scientific paper for a publication. Please note that the format is two-columns. I stumbled across a new problem: i have some long tables (7 columns or so) while other have only 3 columns. I use resizebox to fit them inside and not overlap. However, of course the longer tables are scaled down while the shorter ones look bigger, and it feels strange to have these different scales (unprofessional).

What is the best method to have all tables at the same scale (the smallest will determine the scale for all of course) ? What is the method employed for a standard scientific paper with varying size tables?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Use `table` environments for single-column tables and `table*` environments for dual-column ("full width") tables. Whatever else you do, stay away from `\resizebox` -- unless you want to make your document look like a  ransom note. :-)

Comment: haha yes indeed a rAnSoM note is the right word lol

Comment: I have tried it now, thanks. However all the big tables go straight to the end of the document (even though i use the [t] placement option). I guess because they are very long... is there a way to make them smaller to fit in the text while of course keeping the same scale for all?

Comment: Intentionally or not, you haven't exactly provided a lot of information about your document setup; hence, it's impossible to provide a definitive diagnosis of the problem, let alone propose a specific fix. It sounds like your wide tables are not only wide, but also very long. As such, LaTeX may indeed defer their printing until the end of the document. However, without (a lot!) more, specific information about your document setup and about the actual dimensions of the tables, it's simply not possible to provide actionable advice.

Comment: never apply `\resizebox` to tables the result is bound to be horrible, if you need it to be smaller use a declared font size such as `\small`

Comment: using `[t]` makes it quite likely that the tables go to the end of the document as the main effect of `[t]` is to prevent the the use of `[p]` ie being put on a page of tables, so there is quite likely no legal position for the table so it can not be placed until it is flushed out by `\clearpage` or the end of the document.

Comment: thanks for your answers. Yes the contents is still confidential but i can tell you that i m using this template:
https://www.latextemplates.com/template/science-journal

Comment: You should take a look at the `cuted` package, from the `sttools`bundle: it defines a `strip` environment, which puts its contents text wide. Tables won't float , but will be inserted where the  environment is inserted.